# Photo uploading via email

Tags: image, email, upload, mobile, photo

I'd like to be able to upload photos via email, which I've seen (and used) on eat.ly and meetups.jquery.com but I haven't been able to work out how to do this, does anyone have a solution?

Essentially I believe the process should be something like this:
1) user adds picture to email on mobile device then send to a specific email address, say 'photos@mydomain.com'
2) email server, cron job or something else looks at the senders address and tells it to add the attachement to that account
3) photo shows up on users profile page

I run Apache servers, with MySQL, PHP, and a JQuery framework. I have email servers running Courier, and I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to make a cron job that checks the email account using POP, and parses and process any incoming emails.

To read the image attachments, you'll need a MIME parser.

<strike>For more specific advice, please tell us what language you're trying to write the script in.</strike>

[Here](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/14695.html) is a PHP POP client.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, sorry I thought I put those details below, but maybe I should have been more specific. I can write in most languages, but for this project I'd like to stick to the above, so PHP ideally.

Comment: You said PHP, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you want to write the _cron job_ in PHP.

Comment: true! easy enough to do in PHP though? i'll give it a go now and let you know how i get on! thanks.